# Recommendation for minimal Mac to run iOS Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am rather new to Mac and iOS. I have been a Linux, Windows and iPad user to this point.

I am considering getting a Mac, mainly for the purpose of running an iOS simulator. (I am sure I will discover other joys of being a Mac user, but simulating an iPhone is my top priority.)

Is there any known minimal CPU/RAM/storage capacity needed to be able to run up to 2 parallel iPhone simulators?  Is Xcode required for this purpose?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All current Mac models are capable of running the iOS simulator (and yes, you need Xcode for that, but you'll need Xcode anyway for development).

Apple has a website for developers at https://developer.apple.com, where you should be able to find more or less anything required to get started.

Comment: Many thanks for the info. I will research it thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

The iOS Simulator is only distributed as part of Xcode.  The minimal Mac (any recent model) that supports Xcode will also support the Simulator.  Multiple instances of the Simulator can be run from the macOS/OSX command line (not from Xcode).

When I ran a small app on the iOS Simulator instance, it showed less than 3 GB of virtual memory and maybe 100 to 200 MB of real memory in use.